# Sweet Alert Js: Html content does not change after each ajax request

Tags: browserify, vue.js, sweetalert

I'm working in a Vue.js application using Browserify. I'm also using Vue Resource to consume API data generated in a PHP backend. When validation errors occur, I receive those errors in the error call back, which are iterated, formatted and passed to the "text" option of the Sweet Alert Object. Whenever each error is fixed by the user, He again submits the form and a new ajax call is made. The call back now registers an array with errors, but obviously omitting the last one fixed. The response from the server is the expected, however, Sweet Alert continues showing the same error data, from the previous call, including the fixed error. This is the code from the ajax call and the Sweet Alert Use:

```js
http.post(server + 'lead', this.infoform).
    then(function (response) {
        var sweetAlert = sweet_alert;
        sweetAlert("Envío exitoso", "Hemos receptado tu requerimiento. Pronto estaremos en contacto!", "success");
        this.clearContactForm();

    }, function (response) {
        var sweetAlert = sweet_alert;
        var body = [];
        var error_code = response.data.result.code;
        var alert_errors = "";
        switch (error_code) {
            case 400:
                var errors = response.data.result.errors;
                body.push('<ul class="list-group">');
                errors.forEach(function (i, k, a) {
                    body.push('<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">' + i + '</li>');
                })
                body.push('</ul>');
                alert_errors = body.join('\n');
                var message_heading = "<h1>Lo sentimos :(</h1><p>Los siguientes errores deben ser corregidos antes de enviar tu solicitud:</p>";
                sweetAlert(
                {
                    title: message_heading,
                    text:  alert_errors,
                    html: true,
                    type: "error"
                });
                break;
            default:
                var message_heading = "<h1>Lo sentimos :(</h1><p>Estamos presentando problemas en nuestro servicio. Intenta nuevamente por favor, o contacta a Maresa via email o teléfono para ofrecerte atención personalizada:</p>";
                sweetAlert(
                {
                    title: message_heading,
                    text: alert_errors,
                    html: true,
                    type: "error"
                });
                break;
        }
        //console.log(alert_errors);
    });
```

Is there any way to reset the alert to show only the new response errors at each new call?
Sorry for the length from this message, but any help is welcome.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: it *seems* like everything is fine, but clearly not. I know you really don't want to do this, but if you could create a jsFiddle that simulates this code, I'd definitely be able to help.

Comment: @dargue3 i'll create the fiddle as soon as possible. Thanks for your help beforehand.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with sweet alert, but something else in your code. Try to `console.log()` your API response `response.data.result.errors`, and check the errors you are getting back from the server.

Comment: When tracking the server response, as i stated in the question, the new error data is ok each time the request is sent. If i console.log() the data received, it shows the correct bundle of errors. However Sweet Alert still shows the previous bundle containing even the error which was fixed by the user. I don't know if the nodejs npm module version, i'm using with browserify just instantiates a unique Sweet Alert object impossible to remove from the scope. as long as i have searched,  Sweet Alert does not have a mechanism to manually create or destroy an alert.